# The Remote Certificate Is Invalid Because Of Errors In The Certificate Chain: UntrustedRoot

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I created a Windows Service which self host an API endpoint inside it using WebHostBuilder.

The authentication mechanism is handled by IdentityServer for the endpoint which runs in a different URL.

Everything works when I setup it without SSL. When I start using SSL there where certificate errors.

Also everything works in dev environment when debugging via Visual Studio.

Once I install the service as a Windows Service, From then I'm getting these certificate errors.

This is the configuration in Startup

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            var authority = Configuration.GetSection("Security:Authentication:Authority").Value;
            
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
            .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = authority;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ApiScope", policy =>
                {
                    policy.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
                    policy.RequireClaim(JwtClaimTypes.Scope, "api.read");
                });
            });

            services.AddControllers();            
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

I'm trying to host it as a Windows service outside of VisualStudio. For that I created a self signed certificate from IIS and exported it as pfx. Then installed it to the Trusted Root Store. Then configured Kestrel like this

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
                .UseKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
                    {
                        listenOptions.UseHttps("certificate.pfx", "password@123");
                    });
                })
                .UseUrls(config.ApiBaseUrl)
                .UseConfiguration(configigurations)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .Build();
                host.Run();
```

These are the logs

```
2021-05-07 14:49:04.934 +05:30 [ERR] Exception occurred while processing message.
System.InvalidOperationException: IDX20803: Unable to obtain configuration from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX20804: Unable to retrieve document from: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.
 ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: UntrustedRoot
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.SendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Boolean async, Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.GetDocumentAsync(String address, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.GetAsync(String address, IDocumentRetriever retriever, CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.GetConfigurationAsync(CancellationToken cancel)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: " For that I created a self signed certificate (...) Then installed it to the Trusted Root Store." You should create a CA, install that to the root store, and sign your certificate with that.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more verbose. What I did now is #I goto my IIS #Created a self signed certificate #Opened it and exported it with password in pfx format #Then installed it to the TrustedRootStore #Then copied the pfx file to bin folder #And configured kestral like mentioned above

Comment: Are you using Own to selfhost?

Comment: I'm using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Owin` in console app along TopShelf

Comment: Enabling SSL in IIS: https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/enabling_ssl_in_iis.htm